# onInput issue for dynamically updated fields

Tags: javascript, events, dynamic

I have input texts and I want to do some operations between them. So, I added some events like:

```
onInput='function();'
```

But, some input text update dynamically, so `onInput` doesn't work , and even `onChange`.

Any suggestion about the dynamic update fields ?

Sure , for example I could have 3 input text like those :

```
<input type='text' class='example' id='example1' name='example1' value='' onInput='functionex();' />
<input type='text' class='example' id='example2' name='example2' value=''.$resfromquery.'' onInput='functionex();' />
<input type='text' class='example' id='example_res' name='example_res' value='' onInput='functionex();' />
```

So, I want to do an operation between the first 2 input fields , one of them gets the value dynamic from a db , and put the result in the third input text, through the `functionex()`. If I insert any number it works , but I want it to work even without the inserting.

For example first input text = 0 , second input text = 3 , then automatically be -3 the third input text.

Comment: Can you provide some more code or explain a bit more?

Comment: When you update a field dynamically probably you can call that function what is in the `oninput` attribute.

Comment: Infact I call it but doesn't display nothing until I insert anything..